# Enable Opportunity Teams/Opportunity Split in scratch org definition file

Tags: salesforcedx, scratch-org, scratch-org-definition-file, opportunity-teams, opportunity-split

Is there a way to enable Opportunity Teams in a scratch org definition file?

I tried this in my file but it didn't work.

```
{
    "settings": {
        "opportunitySettings": {
            "enableOpportunityTeam": true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error message you are seeing? I used "opportunitySettings": {          "enableOpportunityTeam": true} in my project-scratch-def.json and could see the Opportunity team enabled in my scratch org. Thanks

Comment: @Swetha my bad, I meant to enable Opportunity Splitting via scratch org definition file. Any input on that?

Comment: I checked the Metadata coverage Doc (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/metadata-coverage/50/OpportunitySettings/details) and scratch org features doc(https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs_def_file_config_values.htm) but do not see any mention of enabling opportunity split setting and I believe this is not an officially supported functionality in scratch orgs currently.

Answer (score 2):

If Opportunity Splits is enabled in the source org used for Org Shape, then it comes as enabled in the scratch orgs created using this source org.

Note: Org Shape feature is still in beta

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_shape_intro.htm

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [Metadata coverage Doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/metadata-coverage/50/OpportunitySettings/details) and [scratch org features doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs_def_file_config_values.htm) there is no mention of enabling opportunity split setting on scratch org and I believe this is not an officially supported functionality in scratch orgs currently.

There is an [Idea](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A0000015AN8QAM) on IdeaExchange too to have this implemented.